# Rails force url to be case sensitive wrt to the parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app with the user model as follows

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    "#{username}".parameterize
  end
end
```

In routes.rb I have

```
resources :users, path: '/u'
```

To link to the show page of a user, I use

```
<%= link_to 'Show', @user %>
```

Now if a user has the username 'UsErNaMe', the above link does not work.
It goes to

```
http://localhost:3000/u/username
```

and not

```
http://localhost:3000/u/UsErNaMe
```

Any solution to this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you are claiming in the question seems to be the opposite of what you wrote in the title.

Comment: @sawa, yeah. Could'nt frame the title as well as I wanted to. But I wanted the url to be http://localhost:3000/u/UsErNaMe and not http://localhost:3000/u/username. Hope the question is clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usernames in your system should only be case sensitive for **display** (i.e. someone prefers their username to **look** a certain way on a page), but never for account lookup. You don't want two accounts, one called "UsErNaMe" and the other called "USERname" to be able to exist at the same time.

I.e. don't worry about the case in the URL. It's not important. What's important is how the username is displayed on the page.

Comment: How do I do that? The usernames should be case sensitive for display.

Comment: If the case isn't correct in the URL, I can't retrieve the user using @user = User.find_by(username: params[:id]). Should I use two fields in the table to store the actual username and the downcased username?

Comment: Sure you can. You just need to do a case-insensitive DB lookup. You need to avoid name collisions where the only difference from one username to the next is the case used anyway, because if you don't that's going to lead to problems down the line. Simply doing the case insensitive lookup is going to be a lot less complicated than messing around with your URLs and other things. Just put the case insensitivity in **one** place - the lookup - and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks! Got it working. I just used validates :username, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false} in the user model to implement what you said. And I changed the links to <%= link_to 'Show', user_path(@user.username) %>